# Move the elements to the left and right side CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, nav

this is the codes that demonstrate my issue

```js
function Nav(f) {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNav");
  if (x.className === "nav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav";
  }
}
```

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #FFC000;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav a {
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav form {
  flex: 5;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav form input {
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav form button {
  width: 15%;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav form button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #FAD5A5;
}

.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* this is the media query */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav form {}
  .nav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
  }
  .nav.responsive a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="nav" id="myNav">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
  <a href="#home">Computations</a>
  <a href="#news">Strings</a>
  <a href="#contact">Arrays</a>
  <a href="#about">Encryption</a>
  <a href="#about">Games</a>
  <a href="#about">Converter</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="Nav()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Dont mind the hrefs in the html Im under testing.

I made a javascript where after you click the bar the other elements will appear. Please help me to move the search bar and button to the left and the bar to the right without using absolute position. Also the float doesnt work. This is the image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

<del>*If that doesn't answer, provide your js too. this answer is only about your style and mediaquerie.We have no idea how your burger is supposed to behave (go away, turn into another icon, else ?), are the hidden links supposed to show on  column(s) or wrapping rows.*</del>

---

You may turn your form into a flex container too:

```
.nav form {
  flex: 5;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  display:flex;
  gap:0.25em
}
```

then eventually ,avoid  reset flex-direction.

your snippet updated with the modification:

```js
function Nav(f) {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNav");
  if (x.className === "nav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav";
  }
}
```

```css
.nav {
  background-color: #FFC000;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav a {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav form {
  flex: 5;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  display:flex;
  gap:0.25em
}

.nav form input {
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav form button {
  width: 15%;
  min-width:2em;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav form button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #FAD5A5;
}

.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* this is the media query */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .nav {
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
  }
  .nav form {}
  .nav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .nav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
  }
  .nav.responsive a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="nav" id="myNav">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
  <a href="#home">Computations</a>
  <a href="#news">Strings</a>
  <a href="#contact">Arrays</a>
  <a href="#about">Encryption</a>
  <a href="#about">Games</a>
  <a href="#about">Converter</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="Nav()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: function Nav(f) {
 var x = document.getElementById("myNav");
 if (x.className === "nav") {
  x.className += " responsive";
 } else {
  x.className = "nav";
 }
}

Comment: that is the javascript file

Comment: it worked now thanks. I figured it out. Just put a flex-wrap.